# How to join video seamlessly with PowerDirector 11

Tags: video-editing, vob

I am using PowerDirector 11 to join 4 .vob files from a movie DVD. The 4 vob files are of 1 continuous movie, but was split up due to the DVD specification.

However in the output file there is a half second split when the end of a vob file is reached and moving to the next one. How can I avoid this and make the transition between vob files seamless?

Comment: Why is this specific to Windows 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: there is a small nice freeware that did the joining job fast. It's called VOBMerge:

http://www.evilmaster.net/?page=tools

No need for biggy PowerDirector

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deleting the last half second of each of the four .vob's? The split might have added some black screen time.